# Is there any standardized notation for drawing neural network diagrams?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, transformer

Is there any standardized notation for drawing neural network diagrams? For example, for circuits there is a universal set of symbols used to draw different types of circuits why not for neural networks?

Comment: IEC vs NEMA, EE doesn't always have standardized diagramming.  How "standardized" are you looking for?

Comment: standard at the level of each operation, for example, convolution have a symbol, adding bias has a symbol and so on.